# Почему если отнять от 2020-02-29 один год, то ошибка ORA-01839: недействительный месяц?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

Такой простой запрос:

```
select to_date('2020-02-29', 'yyyy-mm-dd') - interval '1' year from dual
```

, но он возвращяет ошибку:

> ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified

Ожидал, что  результат должен быть: `2019-02-28`

Почему БД  считает, что это недействительный месяц?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [2020-02-29 minus inteval one year in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60504288) от участника [@Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4443784/tom)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60504288

Answer (score 4):

Это поведение [документировано](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705), и даже сопровождается примерами:

> When interval calculations return a datetime value, the result must be
> an actual datetime value or the database returns an error. For
> example, the next two statements return errors:
>
> ```
> SELECT TO_DATE('31-AUG-2004','DD-MON-YYYY') + TO_YMINTERVAL('0-1') FROM DUAL;
>
> SELECT TO_DATE('29-FEB-2004','DD-MON-YYYY') + TO_YMINTERVAL('1-0') FROM DUAL;
> ```
>
> The first fails because adding one month to a 31-day month
> would result in September 31, which is not a valid date. The second
> fails **because adding one year to a date that exists only every four
> years is not valid**. However, the next statement succeeds, because
> adding four years to a February 29 date is valid:
>
> ```
> SELECT TO_DATE('29-FEB-2004', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + TO_YMINTERVAL('4-0') FROM DUAL;   
>  
> TO_DATE('
> --------- 
> 29-FEB-08
> ```

Добавлять один год к дате, которая выпадает только каждые четыре года, недействительно.

Альтернативно можно использовать [ADD_MONTHS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ADD_MONTHS.html#GUID-B8C74443-DF32-4B7C-857F-28D557381543), которая даст желаемый результат:

```
select add_months (date '2020-02-29', -12) from dual;
    
ADD_MONTHS
----------
2019-02-28
```

Но обратите внимание, как это связано с разным количеством дней в месяце. На самом деле, это не проблема, если вернутся ровно на год, но все же, это следует учесть:

> If *date* is the last day of the month or if the resulting month has fewer days than the day component of *date*, then the result is the last day of the resulting month.

Если дата выпадает на последний день месяца, или в результирующем месяце меньше дней, то результат это последний день результирующего месяца.

Так что, результат следующего запроса, это *возможно* не совсем то, что ожидалось:

```
with rcte (dt) as (
    select last_day (date '2020-01-01') from dual 
    union all
    select last_day (trunc (dt, 'MM') + interval '1' month)
    from rcte where dt < date '2020-06-01')
select dt,
    add_months (dt, -12) minus12, add_months (dt, -3) minus3, add_months (dt, -1) minus1,
    add_months (dt,   1) plus1,   add_months (dt,  3) plus3,  add_months (dt, 12) plus12
from rcte
order by dt
/

DT         MINUS12    MINUS3     MINUS1     PLUS1      PLUS3      PLUS12    
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2020-01-31 2019-01-31 2019-10-31 2019-12-31 2020-02-29 2020-04-30 2021-01-31
2020-02-29 2019-02-28 2019-11-30 2020-01-31 2020-03-31 2020-05-31 2021-02-28
2020-03-31 2019-03-31 2019-12-31 2020-02-29 2020-04-30 2020-06-30 2021-03-31
2020-04-30 2019-04-30 2020-01-31 2020-03-31 2020-05-31 2020-07-31 2021-04-30
2020-05-31 2019-05-31 2020-02-29 2020-04-30 2020-06-30 2020-08-31 2021-05-31
2020-06-30 2019-06-30 2020-03-31 2020-05-31 2020-07-31 2020-09-30 2021-06-30
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60504387) от участника [@Alex Poole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Это проблема с високосным годом, в котором феврале не 28, а 29 дней!

Comment: Не только с високосным годом. Посмотрите,  например, сегодня: `select date'2020-07-31' - interval '1' month from dual
`, даст ту же ошибку.

Comment: Выдаст не ошибку, а 2020-06-30 , т.е. последний день месяца. Вы же месяц вычитайте. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/159799

Comment: Вы не обратили внимания на метку. Разные производители СУБД видят это по разному, [вот здесь пример того](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2a067c4b45fcbe4fe7dfa1b689eb3fb9).